# Code works with a numpy array, but not a 2D list

Tags: python, numpy

Ok, first of all, I realize this code is pure spaghetti and I apologize in advance (Tips are welcome but most importantly I need it to work). But it works how I am expecting when I use a numpy array, and not when I use a 2D list, and I just found out I'm not allowed to use numpy for whatever reason.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is perturb this 2D matrix in a way that makes sure each column has exactly one non-zero entry.  As well, each column has an associated weight, and for each row, the sum of the non-zero column weights needs to be less than droneCapacity.

Once these conditions are satisfied, the total lengths associated with the original matrix and the perturbed matrix are calculated via objectiveFunction(), and if the perturbed matrix has a shorter length, it is returned.

```
def nudgeSolution(fs, fr, spf, warehouse, orders, id_offset, droneCapacity):
    max_itr = 200

    pivot_col = random.randint(0, len(orders) - 1)
    nudge = random.randint(0, len(orders) - 1)
    nudged_fs = np.copy(fs) #Want to change to nudged_fs = fs.copy()


    fs_length = objectiveFunction(fs, spf, warehouse, orders, id_offset)
    nudged_fs_length = objectiveFunction(nudged_fs, spf, warehouse, orders, id_offset)

    i = 0
    while nudged_fs_length >= fs_length and i <= max_itr:
        for row in range(len(fs)):
            if nudged_fs[row][pivot_col] == 1:
                while ((fr.orderWeight(pivot_col) + fr.groupWeight(fs[nudge])) > droneCapacity):
                    nudge = random.randint(0, len(orders) - 1)
                    pivot_col = random.randint(0, len(orders) - 1)
                nudged_fs[row][pivot_col] = 0
                nudged_fs[nudge][pivot_col] = 1
                break

        fs_length = objectiveFunction(fs, spf, warehouse, orders, id_offset)
        nudged_fs_length = objectiveFunction(nudged_fs, spf, warehouse, orders, id_offset)

        i += 1

    if nudged_fs_length > fs_length:
        return fs
    else:
        return nudged_fs
```

When I use a numpy array, it works without a hitch.  But when I try using a 2D List, I end up with columns with more than one non-zero entry (But total row weight is still less than droneCapacity, thankfully).

```
Sample output with numpy array:

Original:
[[1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0]]



Perturbed:
[[1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]



Sample output with 2D-List:

Original:
[[1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0]]

Perturbed:
[[1 1 0 0]
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 1]
[0 0 0 0]]
```

Can anyone see what my issue is?

Comment: After `if nudged_fs[row][pivot_col] == 1` the `pivot_col` is changed and for the `nudged_fs[...][pivot_col] = ...` settings I therefore see no checking of the previous values. That it worked with numpy may be pure coincidence.

Comment: I removed that case, but it still doesn't seem to work.  But in either case, when I use a numpy array, it works  very consistently.  As in, I have ran it over a hundred times so far and have not seen it produce a solution that doesn't satisfy the conditions.  Not only that, but it does it in a reasonable amount of time.  Its honestly mind boggling.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.  Apparently, nudged_fs = fs.copy() was just passing a reference, and both the original and the copy were being modified each time I modified the nudged_fs.  This was stopped happening once I instead copied over each value manually via a nested loop.

Comment: I was going to suggest looking at the copies.  That's one of the big differences between lists and ndarray.  `copy.deepcopy(alist)` is closer to an array `copy` - going 'all the way down'.